# Auto-suggestion in Eclipse XML files refuses to die

Tags: xml, eclipse

Auto-suggestion is just an annoyance to me. I unchecked "Automatically make suggestions" in Preferences -> XML -> XML Files -> Editor, but it's still doing it when I type < or :

Using 3.5.2 if it matters.

Answer (score 0):

[Bug 144313](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=144313) introduced this preference for various types of xml files:

> This patch contains Typing preference pages for XML, HTML, and JSP.
>   These preferences are referenced in the XML, HTML, and JSP auto edit strategies.

Are you sure your file is a `.xml` one or is it some other extension with xml content?
(Like a javascript one, which has its own setting:
[image]

ditto for HTML files:

[image]

)